# Línea nueva no deseada al combinar dos ficheros en C

Tags: c, archivo

soy un novato programando y preguntando. Mi problema es, tengo dos archivos con el mismo número de líneas, y quiero combinar ambos en un tercero, de forma que cada línea del tercer archivo sea la combinación de la misma línea de los archivos 1 y 2, y el resultado sea un archivo con el mismo nº de líneas que los dos primeros.
He hecho esta función, pero en el archivo resultante, después de cada línea del archivo 1 me pasa a línea nueva, y entonces imprime la línea correspondiente del archivo 2, con lo cual el archivo 3 tiene el doble de líneas, intercaladas.
He tratado de evitarlo haciendo que fputc() no actúe si lee un '\n', pero igualmente me pone línea nueva.

```
int combine(FILE *f1, FILE *f2, FILE *f3)
{
   char a, b;
   
   while ((a = fgetc(f1)) != EOF)
   {
      if (a != '\n')
      {
         fputc(a, f3);
      }
      
      else
      {
         fputc(' ',f3);
         while ((b = fgetc(f2)) != EOF)
         if (b != '\n')
            fputc(b, f3);
         else break;
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo leer las lineas con `fgets()` así las lees enteras de una vez y antes de imprimirlas en el archivo usar una funcion que elimine los '/n' la funcion quedaría así (sin el main) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void limpiar(char*);



void limpiar(char frase[])
{
    int i;
    
    for(i=0;i<strlen(frase);i++)
    {
        if(frase[i]=='\n')
        {
            frase[i]='\0';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Como las lees con el fgets tienes que poner una variable char[] que al final va a tener un '/n' y la función de arriba sirve para eliminarlo.

Comment: aunque lo he hecho con fgets y con tu función limpiar inexplicablemente me seguía imprimiendo el condenado newline, pero al final lo he solventado haciendo que la sustitución por '\0' ocurra en frase[i-1]. No entiendo por qué, pero como dice mi profesor, si funciona, no lo toques.

Comment: XD gran frase la de si funciona no lo toques. En verdad creo que estaría mejor lo que has hecho porque así no comprueba todas las letras sino que la cambia directamente pero no entiendo porque no funciona lo que te he mandado si yo lo uso en casi todos mis programas.